# Programmatically change Mac display brightness

Tags: cocoa, macos, brightness

How to change Mac display brightness from cocoa application?

Comment: Would this be on a Macintosh itself, or an iP*?

Comment: Mac itself (more specific — Mac Book Pro), I already found thread here telling that it is impossible to do this on iP*.

Comment: I released a shell utility to do it here: https://github.com/pirate/mac-keyboard-brightness

Answer (score 15):

`CGDisplayIOServicePort` is [deprecated in OS 10.9](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGDisplayIOServicePort) – so you have to use `IOServiceGetMatchingServices` to get the service parameter for `IODisplaySetFloatParameter`. Here's a basic function that looks for services named "display" and changes their brightness.

```
- (void) setBrightnessTo: (float) level
{

    io_iterator_t iterator;
    kern_return_t result = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault,
                                                        IOServiceMatching("IODisplayConnect"),
                                                        &iterator);

    // If we were successful
    if (result == kIOReturnSuccess)
    {
        io_object_t service;
        while ((service = IOIteratorNext(iterator))) {
            IODisplaySetFloatParameter(service, kNilOptions, CFSTR(kIODisplayBrightnessKey), level);

            // Let the object go
            IOObjectRelease(service);

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And in Swift (via [@Dov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105717/dov)):

```
private func setBrightnessLevel(level: Float) {
    var iterator: io_iterator_t = 0

    let result = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault,
                                              IOServiceMatching("IODisplayConnect").takeUnretainedValue(),
                                              &iterator)

    if result == kIOReturnSuccess {
        var service: io_object_t = 1

        for ;; {
            service = IOIteratorNext(iterator)

            if service == 0 {
                break
            }

            IODisplaySetFloatParameter(service, 0, kIODisplayBrightnessKey, level)
            IOObjectRelease(service)
        }
    }
}
```

(code is [open source of course](http://unlicense.org))

Comment: compiler throws error: "Value of type 'CFMutableDictionary' has no member 'takeUnretainedValue'" in second line of 'let result...'

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on Alex's answer:

In Xcode8 beta3 with Swift3, the code is a lot more streamlined.

```
 private func setBrightness(level: Float) {
    let service = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IODisplayConnect"))

    IODisplaySetFloatParameter(service, 0, kIODisplayBrightnessKey, level)
    IOObjectRelease(service)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From Alec Jacobson's Brightness Menu source code:

```
- (void) set_brightness:(float) new_brightness {
CGDirectDisplayID display[kMaxDisplays];
CGDisplayCount numDisplays;
CGDisplayErr err;
err = CGGetActiveDisplayList(kMaxDisplays, display, &numDisplays);

if (err != CGDisplayNoErr)
    printf("cannot get list of displays (error %d)\n",err);
for (CGDisplayCount i = 0; i < numDisplays; ++i) {
    CGDirectDisplayID dspy = display[i];
    CFDictionaryRef originalMode = CGDisplayCurrentMode(dspy);
    if (originalMode == NULL)
        continue;
            io_service_t service = CGDisplayIOServicePort(dspy);

    float brightness;
    err= IODisplayGetFloatParameter(service, kNilOptions, kDisplayBrightness,
                                    &brightness);
    if (err != kIOReturnSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "failed to get brightness of display 0x%x (error %d)",
                (unsigned int)dspy, err);
        continue;
    }

    err = IODisplaySetFloatParameter(service, kNilOptions, kDisplayBrightness,
                                     new_brightness);
    if (err != kIOReturnSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Failed to set brightness of display 0x%x (error %d)",
                 (unsigned int)dspy, err);
        continue;
    }
}       

}
```

Comment: There is already a link to page where I can find all source code.

Answer (score 2):

in Xcode 8 beta 6 does not compile:

```
IODisplaySetFloatParameter(service, 0, kIODisplayBrightnessKey, level)
```

Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'CFString!'

so let' cast it:

```
IODisplaySetFloatParameter(service, 0, kIODisplayBrightnessKey as CFString!, level)
```