# Adjusting screen contrast programmatically in Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, brightness

I'm trying to adjust the screen contrast in Objective C for a Cocoa application using kIODisplayContrastKey. I saw a post about adjusting screen brightness here:

[Programmatically change Mac display brightness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239749/programmatically-change-mac-display-brightness/21655038#21655038)

```
- (void) setBrightnessTo: (float) level
{

    io_iterator_t iterator;
    kern_return_t result = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault,
                                                    IOServiceMatching("IODisplayConnect"),
                                                    &iterator);

    // If we were successful
    if (result == kIOReturnSuccess)
    {
        io_object_t service;
        while ((service = IOIteratorNext(iterator))) 
        {
            IODisplaySetFloatParameter(service, kNilOptions, CFSTR(kIODisplayBrightnessKey), level);

            // Let the object go
            IOObjectRelease(service);

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Code by Alex King from the link above.

And that code worked. So I tried to do the same for contrast by using a different key (kIODisplayContrastKey), but that doesn't seem to work. Does anybody have an idea if that's possible?

I'm using 10.9.3

Comment: I think you've got a typo there somewhere, because you say it's working with `kIODisplayContrastKey` but now you want to use a different key, which also happens to be `kIODisplayContrastKey` and thus is not different?

Comment: Sorry, it does sound a bit confusing. What I mean is it works for brightness with key kIODisplayBrightnessKey, but it doesn't work with kIODisplayContrastKey